# Running code within the same thread when cancellation is requested

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, system.reactive, reactive

I have a thread I am starting with `Task.Run()` - inside of it, I have an observable timer (`Observable.Timer`) that runs within the context of the same thread. As part of the thread execution, I am using [`SetThreadExecutionState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) to specify thread parameters that allow me to keep the computer in a specific "wakeness" state while the task is executed.

When the thread is cancelled via a `CancellationToken.Cancel`, the execution of the timer stops (because the subscription is bound to the same `CancellationToken`), *but* the thread still exists for anywhere between 10-30 seconds.

Given this state, that means that whatever options I chose with `SetThreadExecutionState` will persist *until* the thread is fully disposed. I want to be able to reset the thread parameters while the disposal is pending (think - `SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS)`) so that it doesn't block the computer from falling back to its default power management settings.

**Question:** Is there a way to execute code *within* the thread (since `SetThreadExecutionState` can only be called within the thread to set the state) when the cancellation occurs without writing a `while (true)` loop checking if cancellation was requested?

Here is how the task is set up:

```cs
 _runnerThread = Task.Run(
        () => RunJob(), _tokenSource.Token);
```

Here is how the observable timer is set up:

```cs
private static void RunJob()
{
    _tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    try
    {
        success = SetUpThreadState();

        if (success)
        {
            Observable.Timer(expireAt, Scheduler.CurrentThread).Subscribe(
            t =>
            {
                CancelExistingThread();
            },
            _tokenSource.Token);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        // Task was clearly cancelled.
        Log($"Background thread termination. Message: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample to show how the task and observable are set up? How do you set up the Observable.Timer to run within the context of the same thread?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - just added the code snippets in the question that clarify that.

Comment: Calling `Task.Run()` does not start a thread.

Comment: Using `Scheduler.CurrentThread` cause the `Timer` to block the current thread until it fires. You haven't given us a [mcve] so we can't tell if the 10 to 30 second delay is just the time for the timer to fire. Can you give us a [mcve]?